# Restify res.send () not called inside event listener callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mq, restify

I am using restify 2.8.4, nodejs 0.10.36 and IBM MQ Light messaging.

It is a RPC pattern, whenever the receiver has the result ready, it will emit an event and below restify `POST` route will capture the event and data, and reply with `res.send ()`.

Issue is, `res.send ()` is not trigger.  And I don't understand why `res.send ()` isn't being triggered.  There is only one `res.send ()` in this POST route.

Tried `res.write ()` and `res.end ()`. Same thing.  Not triggered.

Any advice is much appreciated.

route.js

```
server.post ('/user', function (req, res, next) {
  var body = req.body;

  var recvClient = createRecv ();

  var sendClient = createSend (body);

  recvClient.on ("receiver:got:it", function () {
    // receiver has confirmed received message
    // so sender client can be released 
    console.log ('stopping send client...'.info);
    sendClient.stop ();
  });

  recvClient.on ("receiver:replied", function (data) {
    // event callback was triggered
    console.log ('receiver replied captured...');

    res.send ();
    return next ();
  });

});
```

receiver.js

```
recvClient.on('started', function() {
    recvClient.subscribe(topicPattern, {qos: 1, autoConfirm: false, credit: 1});

    recvClient.on('message', function(data, delivery) {
      console.log('Recv: ' + util.inspect (data, false, null));

      delivery.message.confirmDelivery (function () {
        recvClient.emit ('receiver:got:it'); 
      });

      var user = new User (data);     
      user.create ()           
      .then (function (user) { 
        recvClient.emit ('receiver:replied', user);
    }, function (err) {      
        recvClient.emit ('receiver:replied', {err: err.message});
    })
      .finally (function (){   
        console.log ('stopping receiver client...');
        recvClient.stop ();    
      });

    });
  });
```

Output trace

```
body: {}  //stuff here
Recv: {}  // receiver received body stuff
stopping send client...
// do work

receiver replied captured...
stopping receiver client...
```

**Update 1**

If I replace event emitter with another send/receive message queue from the receiver, `res.send ()` is called.

This approach is messier than event emitter.  I still refuse to believe why event emitter won't work.

```
var rpcReceive = new RpcReceive ("user.create.replied", {qos:1, autoConfirm: false, credit: 1});

rpcReceive.receive (recvClient)
.then (function (user){
  res.send (user);
  return next ();
})
.then (undefined, function (err){
  return next (new restify.errors.BadRequestError (err.message));
});
```

Comment: res.send() is most likely getting called, you have no parameter passed into the function so nothing is happening. It needs something to actually send.

Comment: It doesn't send with `res.send (200, {foo: "bar"})`  as well.

Comment: Please see update 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem looks like in the structure of route.js. Actually, recvClient.on event should not be dependent on server.post('/user'). Correct structure should be like:

```
var recvClient = createRecv ();     // should be global object

server.post ('/user', function (req, res, next) {
  var body = req.body;

  //var recvClient = createRecv ();     //commented out this code as this is moved out of this API.

  //var sendClient = createSend (body); //commented out this code. May be this wont be required.

});

recvClient.on ("receiver:got:it", function () {
    // receiver has confirmed received message
    // so sender client can be released 
    console.log ('stopping send client...'.info);
    //sendClient.stop ();       //commented out this code. May be this wont be required.
});

recvClient.on ("receiver:replied", function (data) {
    // event callback was triggered
    console.log ('receiver replied captured...');

    //res.send ();              
    //return next ();       

    /*commented out these two lines. Instead of sending response like this, emit some event from here, which can be consumed on receiver.js. Use something like below code to send response to receiver.js */
    recvClient.emit('sending:response', "response");
});
```

And your receiver.js should have below logic (in addition to your code) to receive response from route.js.

```
recvClient.on('sending:response', function(response) {
    // do processing on response
});
```

Please try this and response back in case you find issue. I have worked on similar logic to emit and consume events while creating chat application. Please let me know in case you still face problem.

Comment: You are right!  Issue was both sender and receiver were instantiated inside API route.  Once moved out the closure, it works!  Thank you, @Abie!

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try **res.json({'status':200})** ?

Comment: Doesn't send.  No effect.

Comment: Can you please try printing res in console. console.log(res);

Comment: I can see entire res object with console.log (res).

Comment: Just saw some1 using res.write(), can u pls try this? I'm not pretty sure about this, but I thought of why not to give it a try.

Comment: Still won't send reply.  res.writeHead(200, {
      'Content-Length': Buffer.byteLength(data),
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    });
    res.write(data);
    res.end();
    return next ();